# Getting average of column just taking into account values higher than a value

Tags: awk

I am calculating average and standard deviation for 3rd column of a file. Now, without modifying this file I would like to also calculate these values just taking into account those rows having a value higher than 0.

This is the command I am using:

```
awk '{sum+=$3; sumsq+=$3*$3} END {print "MEAN:",sum/NR; print "SD:",sqrt(sumsq/NR - (sum/NR)**2)}' myFile > mean.txt
```

Do you know how can I adapt it to get also the mean and sd but just taking into account values higher than 0, as if those rows didn´t exist.

This is the head of my file (and in the whole file no number is lower than 0):

```
A  g1  10
B  g6  5
C  h7  3
D  l8  0
F  gg  1
T  o7  0
O  m7  33
```

My desired output (imaging that this is my whole file) is:

```
MEAN: 7.428  SD: 10.939
MEAN1: 10.4 SD1: 11.68
```

Thanks!

Comment: Kindly do add samples of input and expected output in your question to make it more clear, thank you.

Comment: for the data you provided, your code outputs `SD: 10.9395` not `SD: 11.816`

Comment: @jhnc I've just corrected it

Comment: Can your real input ever have $3 values less than 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it quite easily. In your rules before `END` you simply need to keep a counter of the number of rows where the values is zero. `skipped` below. Then in `END` compute an updated `nr = NR - skipped` and use that for your second `print`, e.g.

```
awk '
    $3==0 { skipped++; next } 
          { sum+=$3; sumsq+=$3*$3 } 
    END   { nr = NR - skipped
            print "MEAN:",sum/NR "  SD:",sqrt(sumsq/NR - (sum/NR)**2)
            print "MEAN:",sum/nr "  SD:",sqrt(sumsq/nr - (sum/nr)**2)
           }
' myFile
```

**Example Use/Output**

You can simply copy/middle-mouse paste in an xterm where `myFile` is in the current directory, e.g.:

```
$ awk '
>     $3==0 { skipped++; next }
>           { sum+=$3; sumsq+=$3*$3 }
>     END   { nr = NR - skipped
>             print "MEAN:",sum/NR "  SD:",sqrt(sumsq/NR - (sum/NR)**2)
>             print "MEAN:",sum/nr "  SD:",sqrt(sumsq/nr - (sum/nr)**2)
>            }
> ' myFile
MEAN: 7.42857  SD: 10.9395
MEAN: 10.4  SD: 11.6893
```

Let me know if that does what you need and if you have any further questions.

Answer (score 0):

I would use GNU `AWK` following way, for simplicity sake I would deal with *mean* only, lets `file.txt` content be

```
A  g1  10
B  g6  5
C  h7  3
D  l8  0
F  gg  1
T  o7  0
O  m7  33
```

then

```
awk '{sum+=$3}$3>0{sum1+=$3;cnt1+=1}END{print "MEAN:",sum/NR,"MEAN1:",sum1/cnt1}' file.txt
```

output

```
MEAN: 7.42857 MEAN1: 10.4
```

Explanation: sum computing for whole data remained unchanged. I added action to be applied in case 3rd column (`$3`) is greater (`>`) than zero (`0`), which does use separate variable `sum1` and variable `cnt1` as counter. Finally I `print`ed computed means.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Comment: That would behave the same way in any awk, it doesn't need GNU awk. It will give you a divide by zero error for an empty input file or any where $3 is never greater than 0 though. `cnt1+=1` = `cnt1++`. If $3 can never be negative, like in the posted sample input, then you don't need 2 separate `sum` variables as they'll always have the same value.